# Is ionization energy non-negotiable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, ionization-energy

$$\text{2Na(s)}+\text{Cl}_2\text{(g)}\longrightarrow \text{2NaCl(s)}\tag{1}$$

This is a spontaneous reaction ($\Delta G<0$). 2 Na atoms donate 2 electrons to 2 Cl atoms.

However, Na still has a first ionization energy of $495.8\ \text{kJ/mol}$.

My question is that must $495.8\ \text{kJ/mol}$ be provided to the system for the reaction to proceed?

**My hypothesis:**

I think that $495.8\ \text{kJ/mol}$ must be provided to the system for the reaction to proceed. I think ionization energy is non-negotiable. Na will have to absorb the requisite ionization energy from the surroundings for the reaction to proceed. If the surroundings are cold, then we will have to provide the requisite ionization energy artificially. Otherwise, the reaction will not proceed even though the net reaction is exothermic. This is my hypothesis.

**My question:**

1. Is my hypothesis correct?

Comment: Are you asking if there is an activation energy required for the reaction to go?

Comment: "However, the ionization energies of the elements are going to be major contributing factors towards the activation energy of the reactions. Remember that activation energy is the minimum energy needed before a reaction will take place." ([source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Ionization_Energy/Ionization_Energies))

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic But you state yourself in your question that the change in Gibbs free energy is negative in which case the reaction proceeds _spontaneously_.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm a bit confused, to be honest. Will the concepts of collision theory and activation energy be applicable here? [BuckThorn says yes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-collision-theory-applicable-only-for-molecules#comment340755_164419); [porphyrin says no](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-collision-theory-applicable-only-for-molecules#comment341843_164426).

Comment: See the first diagram here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/129138/79678.

Comment: The 1st ionization energy is for  $\require{mhchem}\ce{Na(g) -> Na+(g) + e^{-}(g)}$. Electrons being transferred during $\require{mhchem}\ce{2 Na(s)  + Cl2(g) -> 2 NaCl(s)}$ are still bound, not free. There the activation energy is different to the 1st IE, smaller.

Comment: @Poutnik Can the concept of activation energy be applied to 2Na(s)+Cl2(g)⟶2NaCl(s) [if the concept of collision theory can't be](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-collision-theory-applicable-only-for-molecules#comment341843_164426)?

Comment: It is not a single reaction, therefore there is several activation energies.

Comment: @Poutnik [Do all these steps have activation energies associated with them?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtt2c.png)

Comment: Any reaction has its activation energy, unless it reaches energy maximum at the end like atom ionizations, then it would be formally equal to the reaction energy.